# Granting merge permission only to a particular directory of a git repository

Tags: git

Is it possible to grant merge access only to a particular directory or file in a git repostiory? or on github? The scenario I was thinking was:
  Suppose you have project P on github which X is the admin. Y is a new guy working on some module M of the project which X don't care much about it,So X is willing to give Y a merge permission on that particular module.

Comment: Not on Github, and not easily with any repository manager I know. Just make this one directory an extra repository.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this question that I was fined two points for asking. Now, I couldn't even ask a question on this platform due to this question. WTF!

Comment: most likely it is because it is a duplicate, I have upvoted it now and your comment as well, hopefully that helps your score.You might consider to delete it, though.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create a **[`submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**.
Submodule is a git repository inside another git repository. This way your "folder" is a standalone repository and you can do whatever you want with this folder  and disallow commits